# EC2 spot instance - Not allocating as many vcpu as the instance description says

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using spot instance that are spun up from template in the Ohio region. When I choose c5a.large, c5a.xlarge, c5a.2xlarge, c5a.4xlarge and run the following commands -

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l
nproc
```

I see 2,4, 6, 8 &16 vcpus in the output as expected & as mentioned in the tabulation below. The allocated memory also matches.

However when I choose any of c5a.8xlarge, c5a.12xlarge or c5a.16xlarge, the memory allocated matches the tabulation below while the vcpu count remains at 16 in all the 3 cases.

The vcpu limit for spot instance is currently at 6. So, it's not a vcpu limit problem.

[image]

**Screenshot of VCPU limits calculator**

[image]

**Output from m5a.8xlarge box**

[image]

**The limits as they apply to spot**

[image]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure you're not hitting the vCPU limit - can you please post a screenshot of the output of [vCPU limits calculator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-on-demand-instances.html#vcpu-limits-calculator)?

Comment: FYI UUOC + UUOwc: `grep -c processor </proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I've added the limits calculator screenshot into the question

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - THe output of that command is 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there was just one instance running at the point in time I was starting up this instance, AWS saw multiple instances running for some reason. This accounted to vCPU being distributed across all the instances running & hence the total allocated vcpu limit to me was reached according to AWS support. This has been resolved since.